# ELK Stack: view Kibana in remote machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, kibana

I configured ELK stack in ec2 Ubuntu,18.04 LTS instance-aws. I configured elasticsearch, logstash & finally kibana in Ubuntu instance and started those with no issues. My question is, once I started kibana, have to view the kibana dashboard in my desktop(windows 7 machine) browser. But, always getting "This site can’t be reached" message. Please find the below commands for detail.

- Completed the installation & configuration of elasticsearch, logstash in Ubuntu,18.04 LTS instance-aws without errors.
- Now for kibana I installed using, 
  `sudo apt-get install kibana`
- removed the comments of below lines from "/etc/kibana/kibana.yml"
  `server.port: 5601
  server.host: "localhost"
  elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"`
- then started the service using,
  `sudo service kibana start`
- then hit the url the http://YOUR_ELASTIC_IP:5601 in my windows browser and given the 'aws ubuntu instance - IPv4 Public IP' for 'YOUR_ELASTIC_IP'.

Anyone can help me to view the kibana from my windows machine which is installed in ec2 ubuntu instance...

Answer (score 0):

Might be a security group issue, make sure that port(5601) is open for your ip address

Comment: not able to understand clearly.. where I have to check? in Ubuntu machine or Windows.?

Comment: Now able to access the ubuntu ip address from my windows but, got the below message **Your search - http:// ip address:5601 - did not match any documents.**

Comment: In the AWS console for EC2, there are security group options, make sure your IP address is allowed

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html